# process.stdin.on('data'...) will not read from console

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm new to node.js and am trying to get a typescript program to read data from the console.  Here's what I have:

```
'use strict';

import { WriteStream, createWriteStream } from "fs";

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');

let inputString: string = '';
let inputLines: string[] = [];

console.debug('made it here');
process.stdin.on('data', function(inputStdin: string): void {
    inputString += inputStdin;
});

process.stdin.on('end', function(): void {
    inputLines = inputString.split('\n');
    inputString = '';

    main();
});

function main() {
   // do stuff
}
```

When I run the program from the cmdline using `ts-node Program.ts` it prints the `'made it here'` in the console and then waits, assumedly for me to type the input.  However, no matter what or how many lines I type it never resumes.

I feel as if I'm missing what the 'data' or 'end' is trying to do here.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'd suggest either the `readline` or `prompt` modules.

Comment: Try to pipe data like this (this will trigger the end event): `echo foo | ts-node Program.ts`

Comment: A `console.log` call shows  `process.stdin.on('data'...` is getting input from the console - it's  `proces.stdin.on('end...'` no being called that's the problem. Check out the duplicate I'm suggesting for more info.

Comment: @traktor - Thank you; although my wording is different I do think this is a duplicate of the other question you mentioned..

Comment: @IonicăBizău - Thank you; the `echo` technique does seem to work as well.